# How does iterative deepening affect time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, depth-first-search, tree-traversal, iterative-deepening

I have a tree traversal algorithm which generally operates in O(b<sup>m</sup>) where b is the branching factor and m is the max depth.

Using iterative deepening, this algorithm is run over and over again, m times at increasing depth:

O(b<sup>m</sup>) = b⁰ + b¹ + b² + ... + b<sup>m</sup>

Based on my limited understanding of time complexity, we take the largest element because that is the most significant one over time, and so that element would be b<sup>m</sup>, where m is the max depth reached.

So, with that knowledge I would conclude that the iterative deepening algorithm also runs in O(b<sup>m</sup>).

However I have trouble understanding, from a logical standpoint, how the tree traversal could have the exact same time complexity whether the algorithm is run once at depth m, or m times up until depth m.

b<sup>m</sup> is inherently less than Σ<sub>k=0,..,m</sub>b<sup>k</sup>. Therefore shouldn't the time complexity on iterative deepening be higher?

Or is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're asking why the following two functions have the same time complexity in terms of big O (as they're both O(n^m)):

- n^0 + n^1 + n^2 + ... + n^m
- n^m

The reason is that, at some point, for values of n and m the term n^m dwarfs all the other terms of these functions. As the input grows the runtime of the function as a whole will be determined by n^m.

Even if you come up with a function that takes n^m + 1000000000000 then at some point n^m will still be the deciding term in how long it takes to run. In other words, the runtime of both functions is bounded by a function with the term n^m times some constant.

In your example, running tree traversal once at depth m or running it m times up until depth m have the same time complexity because, as the tree grows, the runtime of running at depth m dwarfs all the other runs. Looking at how long it takes to run at depth m is basically all that is needed to find a function that bounds the runtime of both tasks.

To give another example, we can think of two functions that are both O(n):

- f1(n) = 1000000000n + 5
- f2(n) = 3n

It may seem that f1 does more work as n grows so it's not "fair" to say both are O(n). But their time complexity is bounded by a linear function: for some (large) constant c I can say that the runtime of both functions will be below f(n) = cn and thus the time complexity as a whole is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

"Exact same" time complexity is not the same as "taking the exact time". Saying "Exact same time complexity" is like saying "growing with the same speed, up to a constant factor", which is a rough estimation.

For example, if `b = 3`, you are comparing these two sequences of numbers:

```
3^m,             or (1, 3,  9, 27,  81, ...)
3^0+3^1+...+3^m, or (1, 4, 13, 40, 121, ...)
```

Let's denote the first number `D(m)` (for "DFS"), and the second one `I(m)` (for "iterative deepening"), then

```
I(m) = 3/2 * D(m) - 1/2
```

It is certainly true that I(m) is greater than D(m), but they have the same "Order" of growth. This idea is denoted by `I(m) = O(D(m))`.

Mathematically, `I(m) = O(D(m))`, because there exists such a constant `k` that `I(m) < k * D(m)` for all `m`; here `k = 3/2`.